# Magento 2: How to use cacheable=false in referenceBlock?

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I want to set `cacheable=false` in **referenceBlock**, Can anyone help to set up this, please.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **referenceBlock** does not support **cacheable** as an attribute

You have to define **cacheable="false"** within `<block>` not `<referenceBlock>`

The referenceBlock tag does not support the **cacheable attribute**. Hope this info helps you.

Let me know if you still have any queries.

Thank You

Comment: Is there any other way to use in referenceBlock?

Comment: You can set up use only in Block